# What happens in two execution units, if two threads within the same process managed by the OS accessing in the same time to the same virtual address?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, operating-system

What happens in computing system with two execution units such as Core2 Duo, if two threads within the same process managed by the OS(Kernel Level Thread) during runtime accessing the same virtual <strike>memory</strike> address?

Hi, I'm trying to understand the differences between User Level thread and Kernel Level thread and accessing virtual <strike>memory</strike> address? or physical <strike>memory</strike> address?...
I don't know if those programs won't crash and both will give expected results or if those programs won't crash but both will give unexpected results or maybe those programs can crash.

What should guide me?

Thanks.

Comment: Unless they use [locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)), the behavior would be undefined, which means on different systems you'll see different things - crashes, partial or inconsistent memory changes etc..

Comment: First, define "the same time" precisely and in the context of gigahertz frequencies and nanometer distances.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I don't think any special definition of "the same time" is required here.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Given any answer would have to rely on how the underlying hardware is designed, there's no way to describe "what happens" without addressing what exactly "the same time" really means.  Two different CPUs trying to access the same RAM?  Two threads on the same CPU hitting the same cache?  The very idea of signals happening at "the same time" when they run at gigahertz frequencies over nanometer distances through millions of transistors has very little meaning. This question implicitly assumes answers are possible but fails to account for any critical underlying details.

Comment: @AndrewHenle IMO, you over-complicate things for no apparent reason. Two threads can generate page fault interrupts roughly at the same time and contend for access to the kernel data structures. That contention is resolved in the usual way by using synchronization primitives.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Ignoring all that precludes any answer regarding the "physical memory" portion of the question as currently worded.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I guess if you keep following such a line of an inquiry you'll need to answer what is "physical" and "time" and what was before the Big Bang before you can answer any other question.

Comment: I meant that those threads accessing to the same virtual memory address.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can make out from your question, you are mixing different concepts, namely: *Multiple execution units and Race conditions*, *Virtual memory*, and *User level vs Kernel level threads*

> What happens in computing system with two execution units such as Core2 Duo, if two threads within the same process managed by the OS(Kernel Level Thread) during runtime accessing the same virtual memory

Well this is usually always the case, `n` cores/processors does not matter. This is a basic concept of multi-threading. So `What happens` is same as in `what will happen when multiple threads access a shared resource`. The usual race condition will always need to be addressed by the developer.

Now don't mix `Virtual memory` with this. User/Kernel level threads both will simply access the memory address in Virtual addressing mode only. This happens because once Virtual memory is enabled in protected mode, its on to the processor to do the translations from Virtual addresses to Physical addresses implicitly (using the Page tables/etc which `OS` has set up).

Answer (score 1):

> What happens in computing system with two execution units such as Core2 Duo, if two threads within the same process managed by the OS(Kernel Level Thread) during runtime accessing the same virtual memory?

One of two things happens:

1. If the author of the software running in the execution units followed the platform's rules for such accesses, they get whatever behavior the platform specifies for such accesses.
2. If the author of the software running in the execution units did not follow the platform's rules for such accesses, the results are often unpredictable or undefined.

A typical platform rule might be that an object may not be accessed in one thread or execution unit while another thread or execution unit is, or might be, modifying it. Typical modern platforms have no issue with simultaneous reads.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases:

1. The memory page frame is already mapped and have compatible access permissions. In this case both threads access the memory.
2. The memory page frame is not mapped or have different access permissions. In this case the accessing thread generates a hardware interrupt and the kernel handles that interrupt by mapping the page, or generating signal `SIGSEGV` for the thread if a page cannot be mapped. When another thread accesses the same page frame while it is being mapped, the thread blocks on a synchronization primitive in the kernel until the mapping operation is complete (in Linux that is `rw_semaphore mmap_sem` member of [`struct mm_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L381)). In other words, the OS kernel protects its data structures from race conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to "what happens during concurrent memory access" is that, *it's complicated*.

Probably the most canonical report on the subject is [Memory Consistency Models for Shared-Memory Multiprocessors, by Kourosh Gharachorloo](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/WRL-95-9.pdf). The first paragraph of the intro may seem slightly dated by now, but he provides enough background information to make the report quite readable to non-experts, and there haven't really been any fundamental changes since then.

The Core 2 Duo follows the *Processor Consistency* model (as every other x86 CPU), so without any explicit synchronization all processors will effectively agree on the order of writes to any given memory location, but when reading from different locations they could observe the writes in different orders.

Core2 Duo implements cache coherence via the [MESI protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol).

Keep in mind that since x86 allows unaligned access, what looks like a single memory access in a single instruction could actually be two memory accesses *to different locations* if it happens to cross a cache-line boundary. If you're programming in a higher-level language (higher than assembly), the language may impose it's own semantics on concurrent memory accesses (and usually does).

Answer (score 0):

The question `What happens...`  is touching different levels of abstraction (user land to hardware).

Actually `What happens` is addressing hardware level:

There are two concurrent (basically occurring at the same machine cycle) accesses to the same physical memory address.

There the following 3 possibilities arise:
(Given a memory address `X` with a content of `C(X)` being `x0`.)

a) two reads
    this will have a deterministic outcome: both will observe `x0` as value.

b) one read, one write (value: `x1`)
   the reader may observe `x0` or `x1`, depending on ordering of the accesses (see below).

c) two writes (values: `x1`, `x2`)
   the final content `C(X)` may then end up as `x1` or `x2`, depending on ordering (see below)

In cases b) and c) an observer may get the impression of non-deterministic behavior. However, the underlying behavior actually is still deterministic.

The actual outcome of those concurrent (`at the same time`) accesses is determined by the details of the hardware. Mostly:

- bus allocation strategy
- cache coherence strategy

The actual OS being used will not have significant influence on this behavior.
The question already requires shared memory among the (big level) execution units (threads in the question), but processes (separate memory be default) using shared memory segments will behave similar.
Any use of synchronisation mechanisms (locks, semaphores) will just prevent concurrent accesses to occur and this way eliminate concurrent access from occurring.

You may think of atomic operations (usually doing an exclusive read-modify-write cycle on the physical memory) as this will allow the executing execution unit to some ind of "know" whether any "other" operation did occur and such cause a more deterministic ordering of operations.